# Convergence sum of normal distributed random variables

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, normal-distribution

> Let $X_1, X_2,\dots$ be independent standard normal distributed random variables and $S_n=X_1+X_2+\dots+X_n$. For $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ define
>   $$ Y_n=e^{aS_n-bn}.$$

1. Show that $Y_n\xrightarrow{a.s.}0$ iff $b>0$.
2. Show that $Y_n\xrightarrow{\mathcal{L}^p}0$ iff $b>\frac{a²p}{2}$.

I'm in need for some help on this exercise, I tried an approach with the Borel-Contelli-Lemma for the first task, but I am not sure if that's the right way to do it.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some hints:

For part 1: note that $\log Y_n = a S_n - bn = n (a\frac{S_n}{n} - b)$.  By the strong law of large numbers, what does $a S_n / n -b$ converge to as $n$ goes to infinity?

For part 2: raise both sides to the $p$th power, and then use the fact that $$\mathbb{E}[e^{tX}] = e^{t^2 /2}$$ for a standard normal.

Comment: Thanks for your hints. The strong law of large numbers states that $lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} S_n/n$ converges to $E[X]$, so in this case to $0$. Then I only have the term $-bn$. Do I then put $exp$ on both sides and show that it can only go to $0$ for $n$ to infinity iff $b>0$?

Comment: In the case of $b > 0$, you have that $a S_n/n - b$ is eventually less than, say, $-b/2$ by the strong law; exponentiating both sides gives an upper bound on $Y_n$.  Similarly, the case of $b < 0$ allows you to get a lower bound.  What happens when $b = 0$?

Comment: $b=0$ means that the whole term converges to $0$ so that by exponentiating, you get convergence to $1$?

Comment: Not exactly; when b = 0, you're just looking at $e^{a S_n}$, but $S_n$ changes sign infinitely often, so no convergence occurs.

Comment: Ah ok, I got it!